# Are FICA taxes applied before or after contributions to a pre tax 401k?

Tags: united-states, retirement, 401k, taxes

When I make contributions to my employer's pre-tax 401k account, are FICA taxes applied before or after making the contributions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

401k contributions are exempt from federal (and sometimes state) income tax. They are not exempt from FICA.

So the answer to your question is FICA taxes are applied before making the contribution.

Comment: Right, Mike. But it should be noted, FSA and DCA come out before FICA. This might impact who takes these from their pay in dual income situations.